# get % of increase or decrease when comparing one result to previous using dates

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

this is the query I have:

```
select 
    country,
    channel,
    month,
    sum(revenue)
from a 
group by 1,2,3
```

so, would it be possible to get the difference in % between the revenue of the current month compared to the previous?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` right along with aggregation:

```
select country, channel, month,
       sum(revenue) as revenue,
       (-1 + sum(revenue) / lag(sum(revenue)) over (partition by country, channel order by month)
       ) as change_ratio
from a
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: thanks! but I am getting an error as my month column is coming from using a formula ( forgot to add it to the query ). my query is select country, channel, date_trunc(month,session_date) as month, sum(revenue) from a group by 1,2,3. Thanks and sorry for the last change! but would it be possible to work with this lag window function as well?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select * 
    ,((revenue/ LAG(revenue,1,0) over (country,channel order by month)) -1)* 100.0 perc
from (
select 
    country,
    channel,
    month,
    sum(revenue) revenue
from a 
group by 1,2,3
) t
```